# How to use NSMutableDictionary in an UIAlertView?

Tags: ios6, uialertview, nsmutabledictionary

I am making a calorie counter and I have created an UIAlertView which gives me list of food items. I have made a `NSMutableDictionary` containing the food and the calories:

```
@implementation FoodDatabase

-(id)init 
{    
  self = [super init];
  if(self) 
  {
    food= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [food setObject:@"111" forKey:@"Rice"];       
  }
  return self;
}


-(NSString *) foodList: (NSString *) foodItem 
{
    for(NSString *key in [food allKeys]) 
    {        
        if([foodItem isEqual: key]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",foodItem);
            return [food objectForKey:foodItem];
        }
    }
 }


@end
```

In another class, I have created an `UIAlertView` which gives a list of food items. This is the code snippet for the item Rice:

```
NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Rice"])
{        
    NSString *xyz = [foodData foodList: @"Rice"];
    food_calorie = ([xyz floatValue]);

    UIAlertView *rice_alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter quantity of rice consumed" message:@"100 gms = 111 calories" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    [rice_alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Enter quantity in gms"];

    RiceText = [rice_alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    RiceText.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    RiceText.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
    RiceText.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    RiceText.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    rice_alert.tag = RiceAlertView;

    [rice_alert show];
    [rice_alert release];

}
```

I calculate the total calories by using the value entered by the user in the `_RiceText_` and the value of the `_object_` returned for a specific key (in this case rice). But it seems not to be returning the value of the `_object_` as the `NSLog` shows `_(null)_` for the value of `_xyz_`. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: does `FoodDatabase` inherits `UIViewController` ?

Comment: @AkshitZaveri, I am not sure if I am correctly answering your question but here it is: _UIViewController_ is the main view.. _FoodDatabase_ is the data modal view.. So I reckon _UIViewController_ inherits _FoodDatabase_

Comment: have you checked that ur `NSMutableDictionary` is not `nil` when you tries to access it in `foodList:` ?

Comment: `NSString *xyz = [foodData foodList: @"Rice"];`
This part of the code is supposed to check the _NSMutableDictionary_ but from the log i can see it is (null)

Comment: check if `food= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];` gets executed or not ? i think it never gets executed. So, you are getting `null`. Put a breakpoint there.

Comment: Nope.. not executing.. It's not even going to the _FoodDatabase_.. Not even _null_ is being displayed.. what should I do now??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41068/discussion-between-akshit-zaveri-and-anish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole error is that the object `foodData` isn't **initialized** properly. So, initialize it

A nice documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

& fetching data from `NSmutableDictionary`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:

Remember the `key` that you use to compare in dictionary should have **same casing (capital - small) as defined earlier**. e.g You store an object for key 'example' but you can not retrieve it using ''Example' or 'EXAMPLE'. You can only use 'example' as defined earlier. And

---

***You don't need to get arrays of keys from dictionary & fast-enumerate    it***

You can just get the object using `objectForKey:` method. Good luck.

Comment: Perfect answer.. Everything sorted for me.. Thank you!